# Why am I getting an error trying to convert HTML toBinary in ColdFusion when a page is requested by IE6?

Tags: internet-explorer, encoding, coldfusion, binary, internet-explorer-6

I'm running ColdFusion on the backend and wrapping my pages like this:

```
    <cfsavecontent variable="renderedResults"><p>hello</p></cfsavecontent>
    <cfscript>
        compressedHTML = reReplace(renderedResults, "\>\s+\<", "> <", "ALL");
        compressedHTML = reReplace(compressedHTML, "\s{2,}", chr(13), "ALL");
        compressedHTML = reReplace(compressedHTML, "\s{2,}", chr(09), "ALL");
        variables.alredayBinary = "false";
    </cfscript>

    <cfif cgi.HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING contains "gzip">
       <cfinvoke component="services.utils" method="gzip" stringToZip="#compressedHTML#" returnvariable="compressedHTML"></cfinvoke>    
       <cfheader name="Content-Encoding" value="gzip">
       <cfset variables.alredayBinary = "true">
    </cfif>

    <cfheader name="Content-Type" value="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <cfheader name="Content-Length" value="#len(compressedHTML)#" >

    <cfif variables.alredayBinary EQ "false">
        <cfcontent reset="no" variable="#ToBinary(compressedHTML)#" />
    <cfelse>
        <cfcontent reset="no" variable="#compressedHTML#" />    
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn  />
```

Although this makes sense to me and seems to work fine on latest browsers, I just had a user produce a flurry of error message using Internet Explorer 6.

The message I'm getting is:

```
 The parameter 1 of function ToBinary, which is now <HTML STRING> must be a Base-64 encoded string
```

which tells me, I'm ending up with `variables.alredayBinary = false` which should convert the HTML string into a binary encoded string.

**Question:**
I'm not sure I understand what `toBinary` does. Isn't it just for that - taking HTML and converting it? So why the error? Why on IE6 only? I could only test IE8 which is working fine.

Thanks for some hints!

Comment: and no, I'dont want to support IE6. I just want to make sure the code is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by what the error message is reporting, try supplying a base64 string to `ToBinary`.

```
<cfcontent reset="no" variable="#ToBinary(ToBase64(compressedHTML))#" />
```

Note that Adobe recommends against using `ToBinary` and `ToBase64` and instead recommends using [`BinaryDecode`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fc5.html) and [`BinaryEncode`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f65.html) instead.  However, for your usage you can just use [`CharsetDecode`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f64.html) instead.

```
<cfcontent reset="no" variable="#CharsetDecode(compressedHTML, "iso-8859-1")#" />
```

Note that this would affect more than IE6.  Any browser that didn't `accept` `gzip` would hit that if statement.

Additional note, in my example I set the encoding to `iso-8859-1` as per your code, but would suggest you consider `utf-8`.

Comment: What does `charsetDecode` do? Will it convert my HTML into binary? It's ok to hit the if-statement when gzip is not supported, that's what I intended to do anyway.

Comment: @frequent I linked to the documentation in my answer. From the `CharsetDecode` page: "Converts a string to a binary representation." And my note about hitting the `if` means that more than IE6 could have errored, so this isn't just a fix for IE6.

Comment: Thanks! I set up a redirect for IE6 to an "pleeeeeze upgrade" page, now I can try tackling this.

Comment: Cool. Seems to work. I disabled gzip in Firefox, got into the if-statement and received a binary string and page. No idea if this helps IE6, but sure made my day. Last question: why ùtf-8` and not `iso-8859-1`? I have my page set to `<meta charset=utf-8>`, but my main page is in German and when setting the request to `utf-8`, my German Umlaute never worked. Once I switched to `iso-8859-1`, all was fine. What`s the correct way?

Comment: @frequent The page encoding is a larger discussion. I would presume that you're getting the issue because the cfm source file isn't saved as utf-8. You can bypass that by setting `<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">` at the top (first line) of the affected file.

Comment: ok. Thanks for pageencoding. I will test this, but now everything seems to run ok.